# The ConnectionString Property Has Not Been Initialised VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, database-connection, connection-string

I'm somewhat a beginner at VB.NET and I haven't gone deep into what it can do. Most of the questions regarding this matter are related to much higher levels than what I'm capable of.

This, simply, is how I initialise my ConnectionString to an SQL DB.

```
Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim provider As String
Dim source As String
provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
source = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|ClientDatabase.mdb"
connection.ConnectionString = provider & source
```

It's worked for the past six months. Why isn't it now?

The error I keep getting is:  *The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.*

Usually when this came up it was something silly like misspelling something etc.

Comment: have you look at connectionstring.com?

Comment: No I haven't! Just did! Brilliant resource, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MIssing `\` character:

```
Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim provider As String
Dim source As String
provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
source = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ClientDatabase.mdb"
connection.ConnectionString = provider & source
```

[Connection String.Com](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=connection%20string&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectionstrings.com%2F&ei=ei7GUcPnEOTYyAHU5oDABQ&usg=AFQjCNFp35VmkJSg5VOClxRITQ5sJhjCbQ&bvm=bv.48293060,d.aWc)